# GCDWebServer: How to return JSON data when receiving an API Request

Tags: gcdwebserver

The scenario would be app host a GCDWebServer, and when it receives an API Request like a "GET" HTTP request - `http://serverURL:8080/search/brand?query=benz&page=1`. Then return the response with a JSON format data to the sender.

I think I should use `GCDWebServerDataResponse(jsonObject: contentType:)`.

However, I get two questions:

1. How should I construct the json file for response data. Should I create it in swift manually or just save a json file in the project. What is the generic or correct way to configure the json data in GCDWebServer?
2. My request includes a query string("query=benz"), how to detect it by using `webServer.addHandler`. In my case, I need to return the different filtered data according to search query string.

```
    func initWebServer() {
        
        let path = "/search/brand"
        webServer.addHandler(forMethod: "GET", path: path, request: GCDWebServerRequest.self, processBlock: { request in
            print("Search request detected")
            return GCDWebServerDataResponse(jsonObject: <#T##Any#>, contentType: <#T##String#>)
        })
        
        webServer.start(withPort: 8080, bonjourName: "My Test Site")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let serverURL = self.webServer.serverURL {
                print("VISIT \(serverURL) in your web browser")
            } else {
                print("Not connected!")
            }
        }
    }
```

After some research & test by myself, I found I could get the `query` & `page` parameters from GCDWebServer handler's request.

As below code showed, I'm not sure if it is appropriate in real product environment. But it is fully worked per my test.

```
import SwiftUI
import GCDWebServer

class GCDServer {
    
    lazy var webServer = GCDWebServer()
    static var serverURL: URL!
    
    func initWebServer() {
        
        let path = "/search/brand"
        webServer.addHandler(forMethod: "GET", path: path, request: GCDWebServerRequest.self, processBlock: { request in
            print("WebServer - GET detected")
            
            if let query = request.query {
                if query["query"]?.lowercased() == "Nike" {
                    if let page = query["page"], Int(page)! <= 3 {
                        return GCDWebServerDataResponse(jsonObject: JsonLoader().jsonStrToDict(forName: "mock-data-page\(page)") ?? [])
                    } else {
                        print("Page num cross the limit of 3.")
                        return nil
                    }
                } else {
                    print("keyword is not matched!")
                    return nil
                }
            }
            return nil
        })
        
        // Binding server to localhost
        do {
            try webServer.start(options: ["Port": 8080, "BindToLocalhost": true])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let serverURL = self.webServer.serverURL {
                GCDServer.serverURL = serverURL
                print("VISIT \(serverURL) in your web browser")
            } else {
                print("Not connected with network!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopWebServer() {
        webServer.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you planing to implement a REST API that is following [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/)? It's not that clear to me from your question but you have added that tag.

Comment: @jelhan, I wanted to use GCDWebServer to return some JSON object, but I didn't know how to return different contents according to http request's `query` and `page number`. I have found the solution, see my updates in question.

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: @MERN, well it has been a long time, but I think I have updated it at that time. So `see my updates in question`.